# How do I show the value of all the ID's on a web page using Python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to show the values of all the ID's on a given website. Is there a function in `urllib` or `urllib2` that would allow me to read the site and then print just the values after "id="? Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: xpath `//*[string-length(@id)>0]`, loop over the result set, and spit out the id attribute values.

Comment: @MarcB: You need to tell him about how to *run* an xpath query on the data first..

Comment: Thanks I was just about to ask that. Thank you for the comments so far also. =)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this using BeautifulSoup and requests. I threw together a quick example, using this page, and posted it on [Github](https://github.com/lyndsysimon/snippets/blob/master/scraping/get_all_ids_on_page.py).

Note that the real work here is in the return statement - most of this is boilerplate.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests as r

def get_ids_from_page(page):
    response = r.get(page)
    soup = BS(response.content).body

    return sorted([x.get('id') for x in soup.find_all() if x.get('id') is not None])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # In response to the question at the URL below - in short "How do I get the
    #   ids from all objects on a page in Python?"
    ids = get_ids_from_page('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347086/')

    for val in ids:
        print val
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the obvious (but ugly) [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) solution, where you get the page, using [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) or [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), or the more convenient [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and then apply a regex, but I would recommend the [pyquery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/) package.
It's like [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/), but for python, with css selectors to get nodes.

For your problem :

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

page = """
<html>
  <body id='test'>
    <p id='test2'>some text</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

doc = PyQuery(page)
for node in doc("*[id]").items():
    print(node.attr.id)
```

will produce :

```
test
test2
```

And to download the page :

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.google.fr").text
```

And `pyquery` even [can open urls](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/scrap.html), using `urllib` or `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions:

```
import re

id_list = re.findall('id="(.*?)"', html_text)
```

Or a bit more complicated (to make sure that you are parsing it out only from HTML tags):

```
id_list = re.findall('<[^>]*? id="(.*?)"', html_text)
```

This way it would be easy to parse only a specific type of ID's (matching some special pattern)